# What happened to the Calamarain and the shuttle?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-q, star-trek-eu

At the end of "Deja Q," Q (with his powers reinstated) "blows away" the Calamarain Cloud, which he had shrunk to fit neatly in the palm of his hand.

Apparently the Cloud vanished, for it wasn't found on sensors, and neither was the shuttle that Q had stolen. Did the Cloud get "blown" into another dimension? Did the shuttle get sent to another dimension as well?

Does anything in the extended works speak to this?

Comment: In other episodes that involved Q and shuttles, Q returned the shuttle. I'd make an educated guess that he also returns the shuttle here but I have no way of proving it.

Comment: Data says that there's no sign of the shuttle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Shuttle

The shuttle [Sakharov](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sakharov) was apparently returned to the ship's shuttle bay where it continued to perform service until at least 2369. It was seen again in [Chain of Command, Part II](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Chain_of_Command,_Part_II_(episode)) where it was used by Riker to plant mines on the hulls of Cardassian ships.

### Calamarain

The Calamarain survived the encounter with Q unscathed. The [script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/161.txt) refers to them simply being "blown away". The other Q (Q2) expresses no upset at his methods, indicating his approval for what Q has done; *presumably transporting them back to wherever they normally live and returning them to their normal size.*

> He blows on the palm of his hand. **The glow is blown away**. **Q2 reacts,
>   nods okay.**

They make a return in the novel EU [Q-Space](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q-Space), where Q expresses no surprise that they're hale and hearty

> “Captain!” Data said emphatically. “Tachyon levels are multiplying at a vastly accelerated rate.” He turned to face Picard. “It is the Calamarain, sir, and they are approaching rapidly.”
>   “Oh, them again,” Q said without much enthusiasm. He had not been nearly so blasé, Picard recalled, when he faced the wrath of the Calamarain without his godlike powers. “Hail, hail, the gang’s all here.”